# WPF Custom Control with Colour Animation Between User-Settable Values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, custom-controls

I've been trying to make a custom control that represents an alarm annunciator. visually, the control is quite simple and looks something like this:

[image]

The important design criteria for the Annunciator control are:

- Can be shipped as part of a control library
- Has a default style (colours, fonts) that differ from the system defaults but can be overridden by the user
- Has text (usually one word, e.g. "ALARM") that can be specified by the user.
- The text must flash with one of a number of different cadences, depending on alert severity. Cadence is settable by the user. Cadences include `SteadyOn` and `SteadyOff` and a few different alternatives in between.
- When the annunciator is on/illuminated, it renders in a colour specified by `ActiveColor` property.
- When the annunciator is off, it renders in the `InactiveColor` property. `InactiveColor` is typically close but not identical to the background colour
- `ActiveColor` and `InactiveColor` can be set by the user.

I have based my custom control on the Control class. The visual tree consists of basically a border and a `TextBlock`, defined in `Generic.xaml` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Annunciator}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OCR A Extended" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Annunciator}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="AnnunciatorTextBlock"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding AnnunciatorText}"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding ActiveColor}"
                               TextAlignment="Center"
                               />
                </Border>
              </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Initially I tried to get the animations working using story boards and triggers. This would have been an elegant solution but I ran into a brick wall because in a control template, I was unable to use `{TemplateBinding}` for the `To` property of a `ColorAnimation`. After many hours and much reading, I concluded that this was not a viable option (maybe I'm wrong?).

So I tried again using code-behind and basing my solution on a similar control I did for Windows Forms, several years ago. In that solution I have a `Cadencemanager` singleton. My controls then register with the `CadenceManager` and whenever the control needs to be updated, the `CadenceManager` calls the control's `ICadencedControl.CadenceUpdate()` method. I tried this technique using a `DispatcherTimer` to avoid any cross-threading update issues and all of the code runs. In my custom control's update method, I update the foreground colour of the text block like so:

```
    public void CadenceUpdate(bool newState)
        {
        var brush = newState && IsEnabled && !Muted ? ActiveColor : InactiveColor;
        textBlockControl.Foreground = brush;
        }
```

The update method is being called as expected (as evidenced by setting a breakpoint in the debugger). However, the text colour never updates.

So how do I make the colour of my `TextBlock` element in my custom control update in response to a `DispatcherTimer` tick event? I just can't see why this isn't working.

Comment: Foreground of your `TextBlock` is already bound to `ActiveColor` property, so to change it - change `ActiveColor`, and not foreground directly. If you want better solution, please post your failed attempt with triggers and storyboards and we see if we can help. As is - question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could use VisualStates for the different flashing states:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Annunciator}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <Border.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="BlinkingStoryboard">
                <ColorAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="AnnunciatorTextBlock"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                    From="{Binding InactiveColor,
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    To="{Binding ActiveColor,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    Duration="0:0:1"
                    AutoReverse="True"
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
            </Storyboard>
            <!-- more Storyboards -->
        </Border.Resources>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="FlashStates">
                <VisualState Name="Blinking"
                             Storyboard="{StaticResource BlinkingStoryboard}"/>
                <!-- more VisualStates -->
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <TextBlock x:Name="AnnunciatorTextBlock" Text="Hello">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Note that the Storyboards are declared as resources to make the `InactiveColor` and `ActiveColor` bindings work with `RelativeSource TemplatedParent`.

You would now activate a VisualState like this:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(annunciator, "Blinking", false);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I spent several hours bashing my head against a wall and playing the game of "guess the binding" and eventually I did it all in code-behind. One of the advantages there is I can synchronise the cadences across all controls. I may go back and try the VisualStateManager approach at some point, so thanks again.